# Why is it not saying I won?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jbutton

This is my if statement...
The buttons show up like this:

[image: enter code here]
This is my if statement

```
        if((buttons[3].getName()=="x" && buttons[6].getName()=="x" &&
        buttons[9].getText()=="x")||(buttons[2].getName()=="x" &&
        buttons[5].getName()=="x" && buttons[8].getName()=="x")||
        ((buttons[1].getName()=="x") && (buttons[4].getName()=="x") &&
        (buttons[7].getName()=="x"))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"X Wins");
        }
```

So if I select the 1st, 4th and 7th buttons (the left most 3 buttons) why does it not say "X Wins"?
As a sidenote, yes the buttons should have the name "x"

Comment: I think it is always better to use equals because with Strings assignment could be done either with the constructor (new) or using string literals. One of them has issues with using == and does not return the correct answer; but I do not remember which one. In general, just use .equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison between strings use equals().

```
button[1].getName().equals("x");
```

Also, you make sure that the 3 of the left are 1, 4 and 7 and not 0, 3 and 6, right?

Comment: I mean, the positions on the array. You make the array start by the position 1, right? Because by default it starts from 0. So your board would be like:
0 1 2 -
3 4 5 -
6 7 8

instead of 
1 2 3 -
4 5 6 -
7 8 9
like you coded

Comment: yeah... so I should use 0,3,and 6 instead of 1,4,and 7???

Comment: Maybe, I don't know how you coded it above those lines...

Comment: `JButton buttons[] = new JButton[ 9];`

Answer (score 3):

```
buttons[3].getName()=="x"
```

String comparison should use `equals()` instead of `==`

It should be `buttons[3].getName().equals("x")`

Comment: But then why do the other 2 columns of buttons show "X wins"?

Comment: Could it be something related to that you are using logical OR in some places?

Comment: yes i am... "buttons[9].getText()=="x") **||** (buttons[2].getName()=="x" &&"

Answer (score 2):

**-** `Objects` in java are compared using `"equals"`.  `"=="` is used to compare primitive values, and also for checking if 2 or more Object Reference Variables are **pointing at the same object** on the `heap` or not.

**-** So `String` **being an Object** in java should be compared using `.equals()` and also using `.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

**Example:**

`buttons[1].getName().equals("x");`

Comment: so should i check the left 3 using buttons[0], 3, and 6 instead of buttons[1],4,and 7?

Comment: @Itachi it doesn't matter... I always keep the count starting from 0, so i can easily keep the track as the Array and Collections starts with index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your if conditions. It's too long. Mixed with AND and OR everywhere.
It could produce unexpected result.

Also use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase()